# Creating geotagged twitter maps in cartodb for one country instead of entire world

Tags: carto, twitter

I know we can create a geotagged twitter maps using cartodb http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/connect_twitter_datasource/#twitter-api-data-options. But by default, the cartodb will create a twitter map for entire world. Is there any way to restrict for one particular coutry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geospatial filters for the Twitter connector are not available at the moment through CartoDB, the only filtering option that can be used is the one to search by terms.